# Connect 4 against the computer

Tags: java, random

Alright, so I'm very beginner and programming a connect 4 game. I've got it all coded so that two players may play against each other, but I'm wanting to add a function to play the computer.

I don't need it to be really smart and figure out the best place to drop the piece, I just need to use something as simple as the random function to place it but I'm lost on how to do so.

Here's what my code for the basic structure of the game looks like:

```
{
    makeBoard();

    System.out.println("Choose 0 - 5 to pick which column to drop your piece!");
    System.out.println("R is red and Y is yellow.");
    System.out.println("Player 1, you are red. Player 2, you are yellow.");
    System.out.println("Good luck!");

    printBoard();

    boolean flag = true;

    while(flag)
    {
        dropRed();
        printBoard();

        if(!redCheck())
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        } //check r


        dropYellow();
        printBoard();


        if(!yellowCheck())
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        } //check y

    } // closes while
```

Any guidance is appreciated, and just let me know if you would like to see more of the code, thank you!

Comment: Alright, welcome to SO. Your question is not clear. Post and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

> I just need to use something as simple as the random function

Then it might be a good idea to look for it in the public Java API. I't freely available, really! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Next step is to decide how to find a free place.

The obvious approach is to simply use the random class to get some coordinates and check if they are still free. This has some downsides especially there is a chance that it never succeeds eventhough there are places available. Its a random pick after all...

I'd suggest a more OO-loke approach.

That means you hold a list (not an array!) of available coordinates. You need a custom class (a Data Transfer Object DTO) for this that holds a `X` and a `Y` value.

When the real player does its turn you remove his pick from this list. (arrays are not dynamic in Java)

The random player can use the `nextInt(LIMIT)` method in conjunction with the lists `size()` getter to get a random value from the list of available positions.

Each turn shortens the list and when the list is empty (which you can check with the `empty()` method) the gane is over.

Comment: thank you! I'll work on putting in the API now!

Answer (score 0):

Chose 'PvP/PvE' in the beginning and save the state (into a private variable)
Within one of the drop methods, you could check the state, take either input from the console (player), or make the pc to chose one.

Tips: To make your code more clear: My 'WTF' moments, which are the best way to measure the readability of code:

flag: 'Flag indicates... something... I guess'

dropRed(): 'drop dead haha... omg I need some vacations... ehm, it is not actually dropping a red stone? Nobody has chose a place to drop, yet?'

!redCheck(): 'Why is he negating redcheck, but below he is negating yellow check, why doesn't he remove the ! and switches the two methods? The flag is set to false, and the loop breaks. Oooh, okay, redCheck() checks, if player red has won!'

// check r: 'Uh, r is red I guess,... but he already checks red in the if statement, is this important?'

dropYellow(): 'Oh okay, it's always red, then yellow, after every drop, independent of the dropped color, it checks, if someone won and gets out of the loop'

yellowCheck(): 'Alright, same as redcheck.'

// closes while: 'Nooooo ***, Sherlock!'

So it's some small things to change, to improve the readability of your code. E.g., rename 'flag' to 'gameWon', dropRed() to playerRedsTurn(), redCheck() to hasPlayerRedWon(). Also remove your comments, the statement in the if clause should be understandable without having a comment, also the 'closes while' is obsolete, as long as your code is well formatted.